# Network Interfaces parameters

Tags: java, windows

When I type `ipconfig /all` in the windows command prompt, I get a bunch of paramteres info from the network interfaces. Is there a way I can access them programmatically? For example, from a Java desktop app?

Example:

```
   Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1D-3B-5A-7A-88
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces =
            NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements())
        {
            NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName());
            for (InterfaceAddress address :
                 iface.getInterfaceAddresses())
            {
                System.out.println("  " + address);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, once you've got a `NetworkInterface` you should be able to find most of the rest of what you want to know. You probably want to filter out any interfaces with no addresses.